# Always show an error whenever I try to login

Tags: php

Anyone can trace my coding since I don't know what's the error because whenever I try to login its always show that my username/password is incorrect. Even I had try copy another coding from other website it works as I've created another 'new' table but when I apply to my coding login always failed.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="") {
header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '" . $name. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
}
}
?>
```

---

So this is my html.

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- add header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Koding Made Simple</a>
    </div>
    <!-- menu items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Username" required class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">    
    New User? <a href="signup.php">Sign Up Here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try Comparing with `$_POST['name'] & $_POST['password']`  Values not with  `$_SESSION['usr_id'] & $_SESSION['usr_name']` .

Comment: Just to make a suggestion: Use [PHPs `password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) instead of MD5, as there exists tons of rainbow tables with md5 hashes

Comment: FYI your code is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: Debug your code by logging the sql query that you are creating and then run it directly in the DB to see what is the issue.

Comment: I have change the coding as Raghav told but it shows an error mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1

Comment: Please vardump this $result and tell me the result

Comment: `$Check = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '" . $name. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; print_r($Check);` Execute the printed data in ur DB and update the result.

Comment: @RasaMohamed i already do as u told it show the query of data that i've inserted. and error mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters as well.

Comment: md5 --do recheck this encrypt and decrypt. Else do the process step by step again

Comment: Thank you guys for ur help. Already fix up the coding.